# OrientDB: delete record and references created with Object API

Tags: java, orientdb, orientdb-2.1

I am using the OrientDB 2.1.6 Object API.

I have two POJOs with a 1 to N relationship like this:

```
public static class Results {
    private String userId;
    private String templateId;
    private Double totalLength;
    private List<String> visibleFields;
    private Boolean filterable;
    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<ResultItem> items;

    //Generic getters and setters
}

public static class ResultItem {
    private String id;
    private String vsId;
    private String entryTemplateId;
    private String objectType;
    private String objectTypeLabel;
    private String capabilityComment;
    private Boolean currentVersion;
    private Double contentSize;
    private String name;
    private String objectStoreId;
    private String mimeType;
    private HashMap<String, String> attributes;
    private Date dateLastModified;

    //generic getters and setters
}
```

This creates two classes in OrientDB. If I delete a Results instance using the Object API, it will delete associated ResultItem rows correctly.

I am trying to delete a particular ResultItem record using the "console" like this:

```
orientdb {db=test}> find references #15:6392 Found
[{rid:#15:6392,referredBy:[1]}] in 0.014000 sec(s).

orientdb {db=test}> delete from ResultItem where @rid=#15:6392 Delete
record(s) '1' in 0.006000 sec(s).

orientdb {db=test}> find references #15:6392 Found
[{rid:#15:6392,referredBy:[1]}] in 0.014000 sec(s).
```

The console output suggests that the record has been deleted but it continues to contain a "reference".

This manifests itself as a problem when I go back to the Object api and try to db.detachAll(results, true);. It throws this exception which I assume is due to the the orphan relationship.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.object.db.OObjectLazyList.convertAndDetachAll(OObjectLazyList.java:456)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.object.db.OObjectLazyList.convertAndDetachAll(OObjectLazyList.java:432)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.object.db.OObjectLazyList.detachAll(OObjectLazyList.java:424)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.object.enhancement.OObjectProxyMethodHandler.detachAll(OObjectProxyMethodHandler.java:165)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.object.enhancement.OObjectEntitySerializer.detachAll(OObjectEntitySerializer.java:261)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.object.db.OObjectDatabaseTx.detachAll(OObjectDatabaseTx.java:809)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.object.db.OObjectDatabaseTx.detachAll(OObjectDatabaseTx.java:327)
```

How can I delete the relationship along with the record?

Comment: Hi Frederic, do you have a small DB test or the entire Java code to try your case ?

Comment: Not really. However, I have pasted the two POJOs in the description as well as the console commands which show a residual reference after deleting a record. One could reproduce by instantiating the Results POJO with test data and saving the resulting object using the Object api.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your case and I got your same results.

This is a limitation about the references because there's no check on `@RID` consistency and when you delete a document, the deletion of all references would activate a full scan of the DB to search all the documents linked to the first and then drop the references.

This would be a very expensive operation and it would take a lot of time, this is one the reasons because using edges is reccomended instead of the `LINKS`, `LINKLIST`,...

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for checking. Just to clarify, I do not expect the deletion to occur systematically if that would require a performance tradeoff. The issue is that I do not know how to manually clean-up those reference from the "console". Is there a query that I can run for this? Here is a pseudo example to clarify intent: DELETE from References WHERE @rid=#15:6392. My understanding is that "edges" do not apply to the Object api, is that correct?

Comment: Hi @Frederic, if you want to delete a `@rid` from references of other records (e.g. a `LINKSET`), you could use this query: `UPDATE MyClass REMOVE myProperty = #18:10`. This removes the `@rid #18:10` from the `References` of the class `MyClass`.

Comment: @LucaS how efficient is this? Does it search the rid sequentially in the list?